# Disable rich help panel in Typer

Tags: python, command-line-interface, rich, typer

I'm trying to use `typer` to build a CLI application.  I'm also using `rich` to do some formatting.  However having rich installed leads to typer using `rich_help_panel`. I would like to disable that.  I would prefer the normal formatting of the help string.  How can I achieve that?

What I have tried so far:

```py
import typer
from typing_extensions import Annotated

cli = typer.Typer(rich_help_panel=None)


@cli.command()
def multiply(x: int, y: int, exp: bool = False):
    """
    Multiply two numbers.
    """
    if exp:
        return print(x**y)
    return print(x * y)


@cli.command()
def sum(x: int, y: int):
    """
    Sum two numbers.
    """
    return print(x + y)


@cli.callback()
def main():
    "Does arithmetic"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `rich_help_panel` is for setting the `rich` panel title text as described [here](https://typer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/commands/help/#help-panels-for-cli-parameters). The functionality you are looking for doesn't exist. At least not yet. I made a [pull request](https://github.com/tiangolo/typer/pull/647) to add a setter to globally disable the `rich` help text and the `rich` traceback respectively.

If someone reading this wants to get this merged I would suggest to write a review of my PR according to [this](https://typer.tiangolo.com/help-typer/#review-pull-requests).

---

*Edit:*
In the meantime you can either use
`typer = {git = "https://github.com/JacobKochems/typer.git"}`
in your `pyproject.toml` as a dependency or the following workaround:

```py
import typer.core
typer.core.rich = None
```

as suggested [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/typer/pull/647#issuecomment-1868190451).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to review your PR this week :)